# determining a used server's fair market value

Tags: windows-server-2003, hardware

I have a customer that has a server he no longer needs. I have another customer who needs a server. This server isn't new but it will easily handle the job. Is there a way to determine what a fair price should be?

If anyone here knows based on the hardware, here's the makeup of the machine.
http://speccy.piriform.com/results/PSbBt5KqBldaPpQ31OozPKW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use eBay completed listings as a fair indicator of the value someone is willing to pay for server hardware. A [similar server](http://cgi.ebay.com/Dell-PowerEdge-2950-Server-1xIntel-Xeon-Quad-Core-E5310-/160584099307?pt=COMP_EN_Servers&hash=item25638ee5eb) is available (but hasn't sold) on eBay for $900US. I'd estimate $600-$700 for this server setup.

Answer (score 1):

For most commodity hardware, straight-line depreciation over 6 years  is probably a safe bet.

```
Price = Price * ((6-age)/6)
```

Comment: I'm more a fan of 18-month double declining `Price = Purchase * 0.5 ^ (Age/1.5)` as it accurately reflects Moore's Law.